# won't show my balance by "getbalance myaddress" but show balance by "getbalance". what is the reason?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

i send btc in my-server created btc address.

which is created by "getnewaddress".

get the payment also and it's shown by "getbalance".

but i want to see the balance by "getbalance myaddress".

it's not showing. what is the reason?
 you anyone help me about it?
how a account will associated server created btc address?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. `getnewaddress`;
2. `getaccount <result from 1>`
3. `getbalance <result from 2>`

For your information:

> [The getbalance RPC gets the balance in decimal bitcoins **across all accounts** *or* **for a particular account**.](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getbalance)

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7490/what-is-the-difference-between-accounts-and-adresses) should be also helpful for you.